# Pascal's Triangle Recursive calling - Java

Tags: java, recursion

I know this question is old, and I solved the calculation part of it. but my problem is in the main method and I could not find a solution for it.
I need to call the Pascal triangle function recursively, but also have the ability to print it upside-down too. I can print the first 10 rows, but I don't know how to flip it to be upside down. here is my code:

```
public class RecursivePascalTriangle {

    static int get_pascal(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0 || col == row) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return get_pascal(row - 1, col - 1) + get_pascal(row - 1, col);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.print(get_pascal(i, k) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me in this? I am stuck here. I don't want to use any for loops.Thank you!

Comment: "I don't want to use any for loops" there's already 2 in here AFAIK

Comment: `for (int i = 10 - 1; i >= 0; --i)` and that it is a for loop should not matter, if not required.

Comment: Yes, I know. but I want to remove the for loops and replace them with recursions. any idea how? it is required that way and also required to print it upside down as well. thank you, kind sir, for your help.